# Kendo UI sortable template rendering incorrectly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

[In this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/OhzgE8IkgP0TJTfnqYN3?p=preview) I have two tables, the first one displays the data using `*ngFor`, and the second shows the same data but using `kendo-sortable` and a template. The sortable function works fine, but there are two problems. First, all the data are below the first column. Second, the `index` variable is `undefined`. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
WITHOUT kendo-sortable
     <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Index</b></td>
          <td><b>First Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
                <td style="width:50px">{{ i }}</td>
                <td style="width:100px">{{ item.firstName }}</td>
                <td style="width:100px">{{ item.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<br><br>

WITH kendo-sortable
     <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Index</b></td>
          <td><b>First Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
        </tr>
        <kendo-sortable [data]="items">
            <ng-template let-item="item" let-rowIndex="i">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:50px">{{ i }}</td>
                <td style="width:100px">{{ item.firstName }}</td>
                <td style="width:100px">{{ item.lastName }}</td>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-sortable>
    </table>
`,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

})
export class AppComponent {
  public items = [ {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Don'},
                  {firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Dona'},
                  {firstName: 'Julius', lastName: 'Kent'}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a lot, so take a look at this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { products } from './products';
import { GridDataResult } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid [data]="gridView" [height]="530>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Index" title="Index" width="80"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="FirstName" title="First Name"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="LastName" title="Last Name" width="230"></kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

    public gridView: GridDataResult;
    public products: any[] = products;

    constructor() {
        this.loadProducts();
    }

    private loadProducts(): void {
        this.gridView = {
            data: orderBy(this.products, this.sort),
            total: this.products.length
        };
    }
}
```

Here you define the products in an external file and import them, [this is the source for that](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/sorting/). By doing what the ducumentation suggests, it might work for you :) Good luck!

Comment: that solution applies to jQuery, not Angular

Comment: You are right, it does. It was intended as an alternative to your approach, because I didn`t find the solution to the problem with angular, sorry :)